# IOS search bar over Master/Detail view

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios6

I am trying to display a searchbar on top of the UITableView of the Master screen of the Master/Detail view.  Using the storyboard, the search bar cannot be placed directly under the header/banner (that says "Master") unless I have the number of prototype cells set to 0.    However, I cannot make it appear regardless of where it is displayed once the table becomes populated.    I have put it in a view that sits on top of the table (SplashView), and attempted to make it visable/etc  and put the searchbar view on top of the table view, but nothin'.

I have to believe it is possible, but I don't know where I have failed.

Also, it appears that changing the x,y coordinates is not allowed in this case.  Is the Master/Detail special in some way?

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.  Please and Thank you!
:bp:

xcode 4.6.2

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface EGMasterViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *loadingLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer;
- (IBAction)panGestureDetected:(id)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *SplashView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@end
```

and:

```
- (void) searchForEvent: (id) sender
{
    UIView * vptr = [self view];
    [self.SplashView setHidden:NO];
    [self.searchBar setHidden:NO];
    [self.spinner setHidden:YES];
    [self.loadingLabel setHidden:YES];
    [vptr bringSubviewToFront:self.searchBar];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an UISearchDisplayController into your storyboard, connect your view controller with it, and then add the search display's searchbar into the tableview header view at runtime. Something like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar];
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  That would have been correct had I done the right thing and used a 'normal' view controller.  I did not realize that 'it' had chosen a UITableViewController which really doesn't like things being on top of it.  Shorter correct answer is : don't use UITableViewController.  Ever:)

Comment: Umm, no. You can add the UISearchDisplayController to your UITableViewController inside your storyboard. However, the search bar will not show on your view controller, so you have to add the piece of code I mentioned in order to add it in the runtime.